# Am I doing this right? Comparing the mean and countIF for the likert-scale results

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif, statistics

I have these for the likert scale
[Likert scale range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UXTr.png)

When I calculated for the mean, it shows a value for 4.3 which means, this will be under the "Agree". But then, if I'll do a COUNTIF, it was 5 or the Strongly Agree that got the most answers. But looking at the median, it is scored as 5

Am I analyzing this incorrectly?

This is the sample spreadsheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xIttQIH9Qbd_oguXaURJLNSDmNmjLFpl2tQl774w0KA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MEDIAN fuction means: half the numbers return values that are greater than the median, and half the numbers return values that are less than the median. Can return the median of a given number. The median is the middle value in a set of values. If the parameter set contains an even number of numbers, the function MEDIAN will return the average of the two middle numbers.

You have 22 vaules= 5, 18 values <5, the 22+18=40, so it's an even number of numbers. The MEDIAN will return the average of the 2 middle numbers, so it's (5+5)/2=5